# SQL Server: error with Transaction and Update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, sql-update

I am trying to update two tables in a row as part of an Else statement.

Therefore I wrapped my Update statements in a transaction which I thought is the correct approach for this but I am getting the following error when trying to execute this. All variables are declared at the beginning of the stored procedure.

What am I missing or doing wrong here ?

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
Must declare the scalar variable "@parentID".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 11
Must declare the scalar variable "@lastUpdate".
```

**My SQL (Update: posting full query):**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MOC_UpdateNav]
    @itemID int,
    @parentID int,
    @itemName nvarchar(100),
    @linkRef nvarchar(2000),
    @sortID int,
    @lastUpdate nvarchar(50),
    @modBy varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    IF NOT EXISTS 
    (
            SELECT  * 
            FROM    MOC_Links
            WHERE   itemID = @itemID
    )
            INSERT INTO MOC_Links
            (
                    parentID,
                    itemName,
                    linkRef,
                    sortID
            )
            SELECT  @parentID,
                    @itemName,
                    @linkRef,
                    @sortID

            INSERT INTO MOC_Log
            (
                    lastUpdate,
                    modTime,
                    modBy
            )
            SELECT  @lastUpdate,
                    GETDATE(),
                    @modBy
    ELSE
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
                UPDATE  MOC_Links
                SET     parentID = @parentID,
                        itemName = @itemName,
                        linkRef = @linkRef,
                        sortID = @sortID
                WHERE   itemID = @itemID

                UPDATE  MOC_Log
                SET     lastUpdate = @lastUpdate,
                        modTime = GETDATE(),
                        modBy = @modBy
                WHERE   itemID = @itemID
            COMMIT
END
```

Comment: `begin transaction` doesn't start a block, so you'll need `begin/end` wrapped around the else block.

Comment: Thanks. So do i just have to add an End below Commit or another Begin above Begin Transaction as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have DECLARED `@parentID` and `@lastUpdate` variable and inside ELSE BLOCK wrap the whole transaction inside BEGIN..END Block. The rest seems fine to me.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MOC_UpdateNav]
    @itemID int,
    @parentID int,
    @itemName nvarchar(100),
    @linkRef nvarchar(2000),
    @sortID int,
    @lastUpdate nvarchar(50),
    @modBy varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MOC_Links WHERE itemID = @itemID)
      BEGIN  --<-- This block here

            INSERT INTO MOC_Links(parentID, itemName, linkRef, sortID)
            VALUES  (@parentID,@itemName,@linkRef,@sortID)

            INSERT INTO MOC_Log (lastUpdate,modTime,modBy)
            VALUES  (@lastUpdate,GETDATE(),@modBy)
     END
    ELSE
       BEGIN  --<-- This another block here

                UPDATE  MOC_Links
                SET      parentID = @parentID
                        ,itemName = @itemName
                        ,linkRef = @linkRef
                        ,sortID = @sortID
                WHERE   itemID = @itemID

                UPDATE  MOC_Log
                SET     lastUpdate = @lastUpdate
                        ,modTime = GETDATE()
                        ,modBy = @modBy
                WHERE   itemID = @itemID

      END

   COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
END
```

*Note*

Dont know what the whole statement looks like, but this TRANSACTION wrapper will make more sense around the whole `IF..ELSE` statement. dont you think ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I already have a Begin and End around the whole If Else. Do I need that twice ? I'll update my post.